# Gerar Thumbs de Imagens Antes de fazer o upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

Estou procurando uma solução sem plugins que gere thumbs das imagens selecionadas no `<input type="file"/>`, de preferência com `Javascript` ou no máximo `jQuery`.

A ideia é ter algo parecido com essa estrutura:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="file" multiple/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150?text=base64" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150?text=base64" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150?text=base64" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150?text=base64" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150?text=base64" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150?text=base64" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dá uma olhadinha: https://github.com/alineDiesel/Otimizacao-de-memoria-no-carregamento-de-imagens/blob/master/Teste/Teste.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="inp-select-img" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="div-conteudo">
    <div id="div-imgs">
    </div>
</div>


    var _imgCarregando = new Image();
    var _arrayUrls = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#inp-select-img").change(function (data) {
            $("#inp-select-img").html("");
            var countLocal = _arrayUrls.length;
            var indiceControle = _arrayUrls.length;
            $.each(data.target.files, function (indice, obj) {
                _arrayUrls.push({ "indice": countLocal, "url": obj, "type": obj.type });
                countLocal += 1;
            });
            carregarArquivo(_arrayUrls[indiceControle]);
        });
    });

    function carregarArquivo(obj) {
        if (obj) {
            if (obj.type.match('image.*')) {
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(obj.url);
                _imgCarregando.onload = function () {
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.height = 150;
                    canvas.width = this.width * canvas.height / this.height;
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    $("#div-imgs").append("<img height='150' class='img-editar' id=" + obj.indice + " src=''/>");
                    var arqFinal = canvas.toDataURL(obj.type, 1);
                    $("#" + obj.indice).attr("src", arqFinal);
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    $('html, body').prop("scrollTop", $("#div-imgs").height());
                    carregarArquivo($.grep(_arrayUrls, function (objAbrir) { return objAbrir.indice == obj.indice + 1; })[0]);
                };
                _imgCarregando.src = url;
            }
        } else
            _imgCarregando = new Image();
    }
```

As imagens são carregadas uma a uma pra não dar estouro de memória na renderização. 
Existem outras formas de se renderizar uma thumb de uma imagem selecionada, como FileReader pra leitura, por exemplo, e renderização reduzida da propria imagem, entretanto, isso consume uma memória bastante considerável. Pensando no carregamento de várias imagens e nem tanto controle de tamanho do arquivo. 
A diferença do createObjectURL é que ele 'cria uma url' baseada no seu documento com os dados do arquivo e a chamada do revokeObjectURL logo a remove do seu relacionamento com a página e da sua necessidade de existência. Tive problema ainda com memória no FF, depois parei de ver, mas fiz um timeout qndo o navegador é FF pra continuar o carregamento e dar um tempinho de liberação da renderização.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a classe `FileReader` do javascript.

Este código foi implementado e alterado com base em outra pergunta.
[Veja a fonte!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802580/html-input-type-file-get-the-image-before-submitting-the-form)

```js
function readURL() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#blah')
        .show()
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .width(350)
        .height(350);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}

$('[type="file"]').on('change', readURL);
```

```css
#blah {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

Comment: O lance é carregar várias imagens, como ficaria utilizando um `input multiple`?

Comment: @KennyRafael é só fazer um loop, note que o arquivo está em `this.files[0]`, então faça um `for` ou `while` para percorrer por todas as imagens.